# Sumar objetos en programacion orientada a objetos

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Hola a tod@s tengo el siguiente código, el cuál cuenta con un método de instancia, que tendrá dos parámetros (además de self), que se usarán para modificar las propiedades (x, y) del objeto self (el primer parámetro se sumará al valor del atributo "x" y el segundo al de la propiedad "y")

```
p = suma_Poo(2.3, 6.9)
p.suma(1.0, -1.0)
print("(x = {}, y = {})".format(p.x, p.y)) # Muestra "x = 3.3, y = 5.9"


class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
"""La clase cuenta con dos atributos, 'x' e 'y'"""
       self.x = x
       self.y = y

     def suma_Poo(self, v1, v2):
        sumax = v1._x + v2_x
        sumay = v1._y + v2._y
        return (sumax, sumay)

if __name__ == "__main__":

# Example
  p = suma_Poo(2.3, 6.9)
  p.suma(1.0, -1.0)
  print("(x = {}, y = {})".format(p.x, p.y)) # Muestra "x = 3.3, y = 5.9"
```

Comment: En la el método isuma o iadd... falta el return self, sino devuelve un NONE. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si lo he entendido bien, lo que buscas es poder sumar dos objetos `Point` entre si (más bien dos vectores). En tal caso, usa el método especia `__add__`, lo cual permite al operador `+` y al builtin `sum` trabajar con tus objetos simplificando enormemente la cosa. También puedes usar `__iadd__` para permitir la suma inplace (operador `+=`) y definir el método `__str__` para que te muestre lo que desees cuando se imprima el objeto:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """La clase cuenta con dos atributos, 'x' e 'y'"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Suma dos vectores y retorna un nuevo vector resultante"""
        if isinstance(other, Vector):
            return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Vector' and '{other.__class__.__name__}'")

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        """Suma al vector actual (self) otro vector inplace"""
        if isinstance(other, Vector):
            self.x += other.x
            self.y += other.y
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Vector' and '{other.__class__.__name__}'")

    def __str__(self):
        """Método llamado cuando se imprime el objeto (print(vector))"""
        return f"(x = {self.x}, y = {self.y})"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = Vector(2.3, 6.9)
    v2 = Vector(1.0, -1.0)
    v3 = v1 + v2
    print(v3) # Muestra (x = 3.3, y = 5.9)

    v1 = Vector(2.3, 6.9)
    v2 = Vector(1.0, -1.0)
    v1 += v2  # Suma inplace
    print(v1) # Muestra (x = 3.3, y = 5.9)
```

Si quieres conocer más métodos especiales (resta, multiplicación, etc ) puedes mirarte la documentación oficial:

- [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) ()

---

### Edición

Si no quieres usar métodos especiales ni lanzar excepciones customizadas si se le pasa un objeto incorrecto al método suma, la idea es la misma, solo que pierdes toda la funcionalidad extra que dichos métodos ofrecen:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """La clase cuenta con dos atributos, 'x' e 'y'"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def isuma(self, other):
        """Suma inplace"""
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y

    def suma(self, other):
        """Suma ambos vectores y retorna un nuevo vector con el resultado"""
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = Vector(2.3, 6.9)
    v2 = Vector(1.0, -1.0)
    v1.isuma(v2)
    print(f"(x = {v1.x}, y = {v1.y})")

    v1 = Vector(2.3, 6.9)
    v2 = Vector(1.0, -1.0)
    v3 = v1.suma(v2)
    print(f"(x = {v3.x}, y = {v3.y})")
```

Comment: Puedes definir tus propios métodos sin problemas, la excepción es simplemente por si intentas sumar un objeto distinto a un vector o sus clases derivadas lanzar una excepción descriptiva en vez de dejar que se intente suma lanzando excepciones más crípticas si no pude o que retorne resultados erróneos. Mira la edición de la respuesta  a ver si es lo que buscabas